# How do you pass props into a side navigation drawer in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I'm using materialize css to create a responsive sidenav but the props `allUsers` and `roomName` are not showing in the sidenav,
here's the side navigation drawer code:

```
const NavDrawer = ({  allUsers,  roomName,}) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const sidenav = document.querySelector('#slide-out');
    M.Sidenav.init(sidenav!, {});
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id='slide-out' className='container sidenav sidenav-fixed '>
        <div
          className='row dark-background center'
          style={{ height: '20vh', margin: 0 }}
        >
          <h2 className='col s12'>{roomName}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className=' row light-background' style={{ minHeight: '80vh' }}>
          <ul className=' col s12' style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
            {allUsers.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.userName}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href='#' data-target='slide-out' className='sidenav-trigger'>
        <i className='material-icons' style={{ padding: '.5rem' }}>
          menu
        </i>
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default NavDrawer;
```

Comment: How are you rendering this `NavDrawer`? Are you doing something like
ReactDOM.render(<NavDrawer />, document.getElementById('<parent_element_id>'))

Comment: not directly, i'm using this nav drawer component inside another component through which i'm passing the props

Comment: i also tried using useContext but that too doesn't work

Comment: Things look good based on what you say. Can you comment the `useEffect` function and try? May be the init call is resetting the values.
I have to look at the full code to debug further. The component code which calls `NavDrawer` and the possible values of `allUsers`, `roomName`.

Comment: i'hve solved this issue, i'm using socket.io and it was not subscribed at the time when this component was mounted...